# Saving and computing values for all tuples from list

Tags: python, list, tuples, formula

There is a sequencelist with tuples given. I want to calculate and save the C_ki for all tuples. I can calculate them for each tuple seperately but this is inefficient for more data.

```
Sequencelist = [(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1)]

# With the following formula: 
for i in range (1,(len(P_i1))):
    for k in range (len(s_k)):
        C_ki[k][j[i]]= max(C[k][j[i-1]], C[k-1][j[i]])
# one tuple is calculated by setting j for example for the first tuple:
j = sequencelist[0]
```

This should be doable in an more efficient way than running and changing manually.

Comment: What is `C_ki`, `P_i1` ?

Comment: A few questions, what is `j`, what is `C_ki`, what is `P_i1`, and what is `C`?

Comment: In this case C_ki is the completion time of job i on machine k, which is the output. P_i1 is the production time of job i on machine 1. j is an example sequence that is the input for the formula and save C_ki at all moments. I want the same for the other sequences from the sequencelist.

Comment: Want to have another go at writing the question?